# How to combine Observables which depends each other and get an object that contain a value from each?

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I´m learning RxJava and a would like to know how to resolve this problem:
I´m using Twitch API, and a would like to get the streams, and for each stream get its game, and save in an object finally and show it.

This is my code:

```
twitchAPI.getStreamsObservable(TwitchAPI.CLIENT_ID)
                .flatMap(twitchStreams -> Observable.fromIterable(twitchStreams.getStreamList()))
                .filter(Stream -> Stream.getViewerCount() > 10000)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(stream -> {
                    StreamMostViewed streamMostViewed = new StreamMostViewed();
                    streamMostViewed.setStreamName(stream.getTitle());
                    twitchAPI.getGame(stream.getGameId(), TwitchAPI.CLIENT_ID)
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe(game -> {
                                streamMostViewed.setGameName(game.getName());
                                view.showStream(streamMostViewed);
                            });
                });
```

The problem is that in first place, it gets all streams, and then, gets the games, but all of them are null...

My other solution was:

```
twitchAPI.getStreamsObservable(TwitchAPI.CLIENT_ID)
                .flatMap(twitchStreams -> Observable.fromIterable(twitchStreams.getStreamList()))
                .filter(Stream -> Stream.getViewerCount() > 10000)
 .flatMap(stream -> twitchAPI.getGame(stream.getGameId(),TwitchAPI.CLIENT_ID))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(game -> {
                    game.getName();
//How could I get the stream object??
                });
```

But in the subscribe I don´t know how get the stream object, for save in a object and show it.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant way would be to "split" the stream into two.

```
streams = twitchAPI.getStreamsObservable(TwitchAPI.CLIENT_ID)
            .flatMap(twitchStreams -> Observable.fromIterable(twitchStreams.getStreamList()))
            .filter(Stream -> Stream.getViewerCount() > 10000)
            .replay()
            .autoConnect(2);
```

First subscription:

```
streams.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(stream -> {
            // handle `stream`
        });
```

Second subscription.

```
streams.flatMap(stream -> twitchAPI.getGame(stream.getGameId(),TwitchAPI.CLIENT_ID))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(game -> {
            // do something with the `game`
        });
```

Comment: Thank you!, but, I haven´t access to object 'stream' inside subscribe of 'game'. I have an object called StreamMostViewed, with attributes streamTitle and gameTitle. I would like to create an instance of this object for each 'stream' and 'game' getted, and finally, when the stream of data are completed, show the list of StreamMostViewed. How could I do this? or Is it a bad approach?